# Can we have function pointers in Go?

Tags: go

I was learning about pointers in Go. And managed to write something like:

```
func hello(){

       fmt.Println("Hello World")
}

func main(){

       pfunc := hello     //pfunc is a pointer to the function "hello"
       pfunc()            //calling pfunc prints "Hello World" similar to hello function
}
```

Is there a way to declare the function pointer without defining it as done above? 
Can we write something like we do in C?

e.g. `void (*pfunc)(void);`

Comment: I don't know enough about Go to answer your question, but I have a counterquestion: why would you want to have function pointers when Go has proper first-class functions?

Comment: I suppose it is more of an educational question. I have a background in C and just started learning about Go. I noticed that Go has pointers similar to C and so wanted to learn if function pointers are possible in Go and if yes, how to declare them.

Answer (score 91):

It works if you're using the signature. There's no pointer.

```
type HelloFunc func(string)

func SayHello(to string) {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, %s!\n", to)
}

func main() {
    var hf HelloFunc

    hf = SayHello

    hf("world")
}
```

Alternatively you can use the function signature directly, without declaring a new type.

Comment: As suggested a function signature could be used directly https://play.golang.org/p/tUw06LjbWqe. @Devendra answer is similar.

Answer (score 35):

Go doesn't have the same syntax for function pointers as C and C++ do. There's a pretty good explanation for that on the [Go blog](http://blog.golang.org/2010/07/gos-declaration-syntax.html).  Understandably the Go authors thought C's syntax for function pointers too similar to regular pointers, so in short they decided to make function pointers explicit; i.e. more readable.

Here's an example I wrote. Notice how the `fp` parameter is defined in `calculate()` and the other example below that shows you how you can make a function pointer into a type and use it in a function (the commented calculate function).

```
package main

import "fmt"

type ArithOp func(int, int)int

func main() {
    calculate(Plus)
    calculate(Minus)
    calculate(Multiply)
}

func calculate(fp func(int, int)int) {
    ans := fp(3,2)
    fmt.Printf("\n%v\n", ans) 
}

// This is the same function but uses the type/fp defined above
// 
// func calculate (fp ArithOp) {
//     ans := fp(3,2)
//     fmt.Printf("\n%v\n", ans) 
// }

func Plus(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

func Minus(a, b int) int {
    return a - b
}

func Multiply(a,b int) int {
    return a * b
}
```

The `fp` parameter is defined as a function that takes two ints and returns a single int. This is somewhat the same thing [Mue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25814/mue) mentioned but shows a different usage example.

Comment: I think you are misreading that blog post.  It is not saying that function pointers aren't "allowed", rather that they have a different declaration syntax to in C.

Answer (score 12):

A function is also a type in Go. So you can essentially create a variable of type `func` signature. So following would work;

```
var pfunc func(string)
```

This variable can point to any function that take string as argument and returns nothing. Following piece of code works well.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func SayHello(to string) {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, %s!\n", to)
}

func main() {
    var pfunc func(string)

    pfunc = SayHello

    pfunc("world")
}
```

Comment: Simple answer +1. A similar answer that matches the question https://play.golang.org/p/tUw06LjbWqe.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func hello(){

       fmt.Println("Hello World")
}

func main(){
       var pfunc func()
       pfunc = hello     //pfunc is a pointer to the function "hello"
       pfunc()            
}
```

If your function has arguments and e.g. a return value, it would look like:

```
func hello(name string) int{

       fmt.Println("Hello %s", name)
       return 0
}
```

and the variable would look like:

```
  var pfunc func(string)int
```

Answer (score 1):

Array based function pointer solution

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type pfunc func(string, int)int

func testCase1(toStr string, toInt int)int {
    fmt.Printf("1st Function Call %s %d\n",toStr, toInt)
    return toInt
}

func testCase2(toStr string, toInt int)int {
    fmt.Printf("2nd Function Call %s %d\n",toStr, toInt)
    return toInt
}

func testCase3(toStr string, toInt int)int {
    fmt.Printf("3rd Function Call %s %d\n",toStr, toInt)
    return toInt
}

func main() {
        
    funcArray := []pfunc{testCase1,testCase2,testCase3} 
    
    for n:=range funcArray {
        result := funcArray[n]("Test", n)
        fmt.Printf("Run Test Case #%d reference %v result %d\n",n, funcArray[n], result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different way to approach it is to define an interface

```
type command interface {
      DoLoop()
}
```

implement a struct that implements it

```
type Delete struct {
      instance string
}

func (dev Delete) DoLoop() {
      fmt.Println("input: delete ")
}
```

Create map that contains the struct

```
 mainFuncTable = make(map[string]command)
 mainFuncTable["delete"] = Delete{"new"}
```

the call the function

```
func route(command string) {
      cmd := mainFuncTable[command]
      cmd.DoLoop()
}
```

It's a little indirect but it works

Comment: I'd say this is a complicated answer for a question that has a simple solution.

Comment: Furthermore, instead of making a struct that contains a string, just create a new type that IS a string: `type Delete string` and then define your interface on that new type. Then going from `string` to `Delete` is just a type cast: `Delete("new")`. And vice-versa.

Comment: interface is a pointer to an object. so with this "solution" you will have to use an extra 64bit variable

Answer (score 0):

I have taken reference from function pointer in c language and callback function from JavaScript

In c language we use function pointer to pass function as an argument to another function as function pointer act as a variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

int sub(int x, int y) {
    return x - y;
}

int calc(int (*fp)(int, int), int a, int b) {
    return (*fp)(a, b);
}

int main() {
   
    printf("%d\n", calc(add, 5, 6)); // 11  
    printf("%d\n", calc(sub, 9, 6)); // 3
    
    return 0;
}
```

In JavaScript we can directly pass function as an argument

```
/* JavaScript Code Snippet */
var foo = function() {
    alert("Foo");
}

function bar(f) {
    f();
}

bar(foo)
```

I tried to replicate same scenario in Go
Here the user of cacl function doesn't need to worry about what is inside the add function

The user just need to know what functionality he/she needs to perform based on which he/she pass function name as argument to calc function

```
package main
import "fmt"

func add(x, y int) int {
    return x + y;
}

func sub(x, y int) int {
    return x - y;
}

func calc(fp func(int, int) int, x, y int) {
    fmt.Println(fp(x, y));
}

func main() {
    calc(add, 5, 6); // 11
    calc(sub, 7, 4); // 3

    calc(func(x, y int) int{
        return x * y;
    }, 5, 3); //this will print 15

}
```

Also if required we can create anonymous function like we created for multiplication

And if you want to use pointer to function directly then following snippet would work

```
package main
import "fmt"

func greet(){
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
}

func main() {

    fptr := greet
    fmt.Println(fptr) //this will print address
    fptr()
}
```

I hope this will help.