# use string as function name - golang

Tags: string, function, dictionary, go

Is theere a way to use a string as a function name and call it?

I have a map of strings to function names
`stuff := map[string]string{'keyword','function'}`

and when the `keyword` is used, i want to call `function` with 2 arguments
`stuff['keyword'](arg1,arg2)`

But it gives me this error:

```
cannot call non-function key (type string)
```

Is there a way to keep my `string` to `string` map and still achieve this?

Comment: You probably want [function variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601796/can-we-have-function-pointers-in-google-go), not function _names_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang: pointer to function from string (function's name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017979/golang-pointer-to-function-from-string-functions-name)

Answer (score 1):

The map you're using isn't syntactically valid. You probably want something like this:

```
stuff := map[string]func(string, string)
```

You would then be able to use your string key to pull out a function from the map and call it:

```
stuff["keyword"]("foo", "goo")
```

GoPlay:
https://play.golang.org/p/DNALJOmoiZ